# How can I call event handlers for button clicks in a Xamarin calculator app?

Tags: c#, android, iphone, calculator

I am a newbie in programming and I am trying to build a sort of calculator that does certain operations by clicking in a couple of buttons. I have three buttons:

- One elevates an X number to the cube. Meaning 3 times the same number.
- The second one calculates the square of X number. So, twice the same number
- The last one just has a sum operation.

My issue is I am not sure how can I call the event handler. What is the right format to use in this case to have my operation calls or actions to work fine. I am getting an error but I am putting the code here of my app that I worked on in C# with Xamarin. I would very much appreciate it if you could please help me out understand how I could call out my operations. Thank you!

Main page.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CalculatorRX.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Calculador" FontSize="Title" />
            <Label Text="Escriba un valor y oprima el botón adecuado" FontSize="Default" />
            <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Escriba un número" x:Name="Entrada" />
            <Button Text="X+x" x:Name="EquisMas" />
            <Button Text="Cuadrado" x:Name="EquisCuadrado" />
            <Button Text="Cubo" x:Name="EquisCubo" />
            <Button Text="CL" x:Name="CL" />
            <Label Text="0.00" FontSize="Title" HorizontalOptions="End" x:Name="Resultado" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Main Page.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CalculatorRX
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CL.Clicked += CL_Clicked;
            EquisMas.Clicked += EquisMas_Clicked;
            EquisCuadrado.Clicked += EquisCuadrado_Clicked;
            EquisCubo.Clicked += EquisCubo_Clicked;
        }

        private void EquisCubo_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            public int xcubo(int cubo)
            {
                xcube = return cubo * cubo * cubo;
            }
        }

        private void EquisCuadrado_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            public int xcuadrado(int cubo)
            {
                xsquare = return cuadrado * cuadrado;
            }
        }

        private void EquisMas_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            public int xsum(int a, int b)
            {
                return a + b;
            }
        }

        private void CL_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Entrada.Text = "";
            Resultado.Text = "0.00";
        }
    }
}
```

This is how my app looks like the top part says "Calculator" "Write a number and click on the right button"

Cuadrado is Squared, Cubo us cubed.

[App image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW8fb.png)

I tried putting the actions of the event handlers like this:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CL.Clicked += CL_Clicked;
            EquisMas.Clicked += EquisMas_Clicked;
            EquisCuadrado.Clicked += EquisCuadrado_Clicked;
            EquisCubo.Clicked += EquisCubo_Clicked;
        }

        private void EquisCubo_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            public int xcubo(int cubo)
            {
                xcube = return cubo * cubo * cubo;
            }
        }

        private void EquisCuadrado_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            public int xcuadrado(int cubo)
            {
                xsquare = return cuadrado * cuadrado;
            }
        }

        private void EquisMas_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            public int xsum(int a, int b)
            {
                return a + b;
            }
        }
```

But I am getting an error that I am not implementing the operations or the action right. I would very much appreciate your help!